# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) in iOS app after deleting AdMob

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I tried to use AdMob in my iOS app and incorporated it to my iOS project, but after then I decided to delete it. What I did was add those files that AdMob provide as well as lots of required frameworks, and then delete those files. However, now my iOS app is not working at all, with the error of the `clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`.

I also got the following warnings:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/myusername/My App Name/My'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LApp'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LName'
```

I think I was quite idiotic to include whitespaces in my iOS app, but this is my first iOS app development and I didn't know that the app name is used as a directory name.

So my question is, why is my app suddenly not working after deleting AdMob? And ultimately should I create my app again from scratch using an app name not including whitespaces?

I use iOS 7 and Xcode 5.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your delete these 3 things in your library search path

```
'-L/Users/myusername/My App Name/My'
'-LApp'
'-LName'
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I found the search path answer here over SO before posing this question, but my Library Search Paths are empty in both Debug and Release.